# Adding an element in a nested list based on condition

Tags: python

I was wondering if you could help me simplify my code or find an efficient method. I am given a nested array and I wish to add the second element based on the first nested item.

```
[('dog','1'),('dog','2'),('cat',1'),('cat','2')]
```

This will result in:

```
[('dog','3'),('cat','3')]
```

I would want the numbers to be strings instead of int type. Here is my code below:

```
dddd=[]
        dddd=result_1_ce+result_2_ce+result_3_ce+result_4_ce
#Sum all of the elements from a prior find dddd stores [('dog','1'),('dog','2'),('cat',1'),('cat','2')]

        newlist = [[int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in sub] for sub in dddd]
        
        grouped = dict()
        grouped.update((name,grouped.get(name,0)+value) for name,value in newlist)
        dddd = [*map(list,grouped.items())]

#Of this manipulation display it in reverse order
        dddd=sorted(dddd,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
        X = [tuple(i) for i in dddd]
        print("Findings:",X)
```

Comment: The fact that you want the data to be structured this way, and for the "numbers to be strings instead of int type" (even though the only thing you have shown us that you want to *do with* them is mathematical), *is why* the code is complex.

Comment: And if you really need to have strings at some point, then convert the numbers to strings *at the point where you need to*. Also, unless your real code has a different structure - but then the example in your code is not really adequately chosen - you data would be simply represented by something like `data = {'dog':2, 'cat':2}` and your expected output would just be `[(k, v+1) for k, v in data.items()]`

Comment: Thanks! The data is originally given to me as strings (numbers are given to me as strings) So I had to convert them from strings to int so I could sum them, then back to strings at the very end for the desired output. I am trying to simplify my code.

Answer (score 0):

This code work

I am writing a comment where I change the code.

```py
dddd=result_1_ce+result_2_ce+result_3_ce+result_4_ce

#Sum all of the elements from a prior find dddd stores [('dog','1'),('dog','2'),('cat',1'),('cat','2')]

newlist = [[int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in sub] for sub in dddd]

grouped = dict()
grouped.update((name,grouped.get(name,0)+value) for name,value in newlist)
dddd = [*map(list,grouped.items())]

#Of this manipulation display it in reverse order
dddd=sorted(dddd,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
X = [tuple([f,str(s)]) for f,s in dddd]  # get two both element from the list of list and change second('s) element to str.
print("Findings:",X)
```

OUTPUT

```py
Findings: [('dog', '3'), ('cat', '3')]
```

You `dddd` list is looks like this `[['dog', 3], ['cat', 3]]`.

```py
# If I write This

dddd = [['dog', 3], ['cat', 3]]

for f,s in dddd: # (f is for 'dog' and 'cat) and (s is for 3 and 3)
    print(f)
    print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I was wondering if you could simplify my given code? Or make it faster?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, a very simple approach would be to convert to a dictionary first, and it is a good data structure for grouping. Also, use an integer to sum the numbers. You can use `int` of `str` if you are unsure if each number value will be `int` or `str`. Then to get the output of list of tuples, you just convert with a simple comprehension.

```py
l = [("dog", "1"), ("dog", "2"), ("cat", 1), ("cat", "2")]
d = {}
for t in l:
    d[t[0]] = d.setdefault(t[0], 0) + int(str(t[1]))

print([(k, str(v)) for k, v in d.items()])
```

Output:

```
[('dog', '3'), ('cat', '3')]
```